# How to implement my android application use less battery usage while running the Application?

Tags: android

I am implementing an android application i need to reduce the battery usage while using(running) my application on android device. I don't know how to restrict the battery usage. Please help me if any one have idea about this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You want to reduce the overall battery usage?, or do you want to create your application so that you use the minimal amount of battery?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

Visit the above link it will be helpful for you ....